# Azure publish package not including all files

Tags: azure

I have couple of  config, dll and an exe file located in the bin folder and included in project. The files are set as Content and Copy Always.
When I debug the project locally, all works fine, the problem is when I publish the cloud service, the files are missing. The files are being omitted by the Azure publish process and are missing from the deployment package file.

How do I force the files to be included in the package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a duplicate of [Windows Azure not generating aspx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313677/windows-azure-not-generating-aspx-files)

Here is a quote from that post that may offer a solution:

I've had a similar issue with deploying Spark ViewEngine files in an MVC3 app. Solution for me was to make sure the files were part of the project (see smarx answer), and to explicitly set the Build Action to Content for each file. –  kenxl Mar 3 '11 at 9:09

Comment: This was it for me.  Recommend opening the .csproj file in notepad++ or something and doing a find/replace on "None Include" => "Content Include".  (ONE AT A TIME!  You don't want to accidentally include something that should be left out.)